# How to convert mp4 to mkv H.264 with gst-launch-1.0 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264

Is my code correct ?
I try to convert .mp4 to .mkv H.264 with gst-launch-1.0 on Raspberry Pi

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=sample_mpeg4.mp4 ! omxmpeg4videodec ! omxh264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=out.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors? Please remember to mention that in future questions as it helps narrowing down the problems.

It should not be right, .mp4 is usually a termination for mp4 container format and not for mpeg4 video codec. You should need something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=sample_mpeg4.mp4 ! qtdemux ! omxmpeg4videodec ! queue ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=out.mkv
```

This will only convert the video, audio on the original media file will be lost. It might also be more practical to just use uridecodebin for the decoding part:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=file:///path/to/sample.mp4 ! queue ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=out.mkv
```